# Python - Matching exact string for variable with REGEX

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a quick question about my script :

I want to check the form of a variable before processing, this may only use 3 notations :

1. 'Module' ( strings only )
2. 'example::module::submodule'
   ( The :: can occur 1 to X times )
3. The string must not contain the following characters : '/*?"<>|'

I have now written this REGEX command and would like to know if this is so optimal, or there is a better solution :

```
if( re.match( '(^[\/\*?"<>|])|(\w+::\w+)|([A-Za-z]+$)' , Module ) ) : 
    print( f"[ MSG ] Processing Module '{Module}' ..." )
else :
    print( f"[ ERROR ] The Specified Module '{Module}' Is Not Allowed !"
```

Output :

```
'Test Environment' -> OK
'Test Environment::Test::New' -> OK 
'Test Environment:Test::New' -> Not Allowed
'Test Environment' - Not Allowed
```

The tests were successful, but I am not sure.

Thanks in advance
NumeroUnoDE

Comment: Your 4th example is identical to the 1st.  Are these allowed or disallowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would express your regex as:

```
^\w+(?:(?: |::)\w+)*$
```

Explanation:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `\w+` match a word
- `(?:`

  - `(?: |::)` match space or `::` one time
  - `\w+` followed by a word
- `)*` zero or more times
- `$` end of the string

### Demo

Comment: Nice, this seems to work perfectly as i don't have to eliminate the special characters seperately. Thanks a lot Bro, also for the quick response ;-)

Comment: @NumeroUnoDE Please don't forget to update/accept this answer as well as other answers for your questions on StackOverflow. Voting is essential for StackOverflow as mentioned e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).